# ItemsControl comma separated values in UWP app

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I am trying to bind name with comma-separated values. In the last item I don't want to add a comma. Can you please let me know how to remove the last comma in WinRT application?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding xxxx}" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-6,0,0" >    
                                        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="name" Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{ThemeResource TileContentHyperlinkStyle}"  ></HyperlinkButton>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="Comma" x:Uid="/Resources/Comma" Style="{ThemeResource TileContentStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                             </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Example output:

`Ramesh ,Sutha,Nikhil,`       <=== (need to remove last comma)

Comment: Use an IValueConverter to format your data for display. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag in your view model to detect whether to show the comma. For example:

In `MyViewModel`, add a `IsLast` property as the flag:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsLast { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Then in XAML, bind the `Visibility` property of `TextBlock` to `IsLast`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="suspectname"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Content="{Binding Name}"
                                 Style="{ThemeResource IncidentSmallTileContentHyperlinkStyle}" />
                <TextBlock x:Uid="/Resources/Comma"
                           x:Name="Comma"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Style="{ThemeResource IncidentSmallTileContentStyle}"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsLast,
                                                Converter={StaticResource MyVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here we need a `Converter` to convert `bool` to `Visibility`:

```cs
public class MyVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var isLast = (bool)value;
        if (isLast)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After this, we can add some data to have a test:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    List<MyViewModel> MyList = new List<MyViewModel>() {
        new MyViewModel() { Name = "Ramesh" },
        new MyViewModel() { Name = "Sutha" },
        new MyViewModel() { Name = "Nikhil", IsLast = true }
    };
    this.DataContext = MyList;
}
```

**Update:**

Adding a flag for comma in the viewmodel is not a good approach. Using a data template selector to switch between a template with and without the comma may be a better way.

To do this, we need two templates first, the template for the first item should have no comma and the others need a comma:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommonDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Comma"
                   Margin="0,0,5,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="," />
        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="suspectname"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FirstDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="suspectname"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then we need to create a data template selector class which inherits from [`DataTemplateSelector` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) and override the [`SelectTemplateCore` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore.aspx) to implement the logic. In the method, we can use [`ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemscontrolfromitemcontainer.aspx) to get the `ItemsControl` and [`ItemsControl.IndexFromContainer` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer.aspx) to get the index of the container then detect whether the item is the first item of the `ItemsControl` by comparing the index:

```cs
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CommonTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FirstTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        if (itemsControl.IndexFromContainer(container) == 0)
        {
            return FirstTemplate;
        }
        return CommonTemplate;

    }
}
```

After this we can add `MyTemplateSelector` in `Page.Resources` like following:

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
                          CommonTemplate="{StaticResource CommonDataTemplate}"
                          FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstDataTemplate}" />
```

Then we can use it in `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks jay ... I have followed same ..its working for now

Comment: @SuthaharJ: Adding a flag for comma in the viewmodel is not a good approach. I updated my answer and use a data template selector to switch between a template with and without the comma. With this approach, we do not need to change the viewmodel, you can have a check.